# PaykeyDuration and Paypal IPN

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using angelleye's paypal php library for handling premium accounts on our website... I am able to create the payment url with the paykey using Adaptive payments pay request, once the registration form is filled(the details are stored in the database as well with the generated tracking id) and the user will be redirected to the paypal url... I have set the value for the paykeyduration as 5mins20secs(which is the minimum we can set) so that the payment url will expire after 5mins20secs...

I need to delete the registration details from the database once the paykey is expired... Will IPN notify the expiration of a paykey?

Answer (score 0):

IPN won't be triggered when a paykey expires, but it would be triggered when the payment is completed, so you could go ahead and do whatever you need to do with the data based on the completed payment.